# Wrong error message

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-1.7

This is how it looks when i try to buy too many items of one product:
**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3E6.png)**
How to fix it? thank you:)

product_list.py

```
 {% for product in products %}
        <li>
        <b>{{ product }}</b>
            ({{ product.quantity }} available)

        (price: {{ product.price }})

        <form method="post" action=".">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ shop_form.as_p }}
            <input type="hidden" id="{{ product.id }}"  name="product_id"  value={{ product.id }} />
            <input type="submit" value="buy"/>
        </form>
    </li><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def product_list(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_id = request.POST['product_id']
        shop_form = ShopForm(data=request.POST, request_product_id=request.POST['product_id'])
        if shop_form.is_valid():

            quantity = int(request.POST['quantity'])

            product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

            price = int(product.price * quantity)

            request.session['koszyk'][product.name] = product.price
            request.session['koszyk']['cena'] += price



            return redirect('/products')
    else:
        shop_form = ShopForm()

    return render(request,
                  'product_list.html',
                  {'shop_form': shop_form, 'products': products})
```

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request_product_id = kwargs.pop('request_product_id', None)

    super(ShopForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields['quantity'].widget.attrs['id'] = "id_quantity_{0}".format(
        self.request_product_id
    )

def clean(self):
    q = self.cleaned_data['quantity']
    request_product_id = self.request_product_id
    product_quantity = Product.objects.get(id=request_product_id).quantity

    if int(q) > int(product_quantity):
        message = "we have only "
        raise ValidationError("we have only %s :(" %(product_quantity))
```

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating the *same* form for different products, that's why you are seeing the error message for the first one in all of them.

If you are trying to edit multiple objects at once, you should use a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/formsets/) instead.

Comment: yes im repeating the same form. do i need to add unique id to each form? how to do it? please help me with code sample:(

Comment: You need to use a formset instead of a single form as I stated. There is a good tutorial at https://godjango.com/9-forms-part-4-formsets/ which details the use of formsets.